# Google map fragment crashes when clicked twice or changed fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2

I have a fragment navigation issue. I made a MainActivity with a fragment using GoogleMap. With a NavigationDrawer, I choose to go to the GoogleMapFragment, it works, but if I change the fragment, and want to go back to my GoogleMapFragment already initiated, it crashs.

LogCat :

```
04-24 18:03:19.576: D/OpenGLRenderer(1165): Enabling debug mode 0
04-24 18:03:23.354: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1165): Google Play services is missing.
04-24 18:03:23.364: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1165): Google Play services is missing.
04-24 18:03:23.374: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1165): Google Play services is missing.
04-24 18:03:23.384: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1165): Google Play services is missing.
04-24 18:03:23.384: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1165): Google Play services is missing.
04-24 18:03:23.404: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1165): Google Play services is missing.
04-24 18:03:23.415: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1165): Google Play services is missing.
04-24 18:03:23.415: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1165): Google Play services is missing.
04-24 18:03:23.424: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1165): Google Play services is missing.
04-24 18:03:23.454: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1165): Google Play services is missing.
04-24 18:03:23.454: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1165): Google Play services is missing.
04-24 18:03:23.465: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1165): Google Play services is missing.
04-24 18:03:23.474: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1165): Google Play services is missing.
04-24 18:03:23.484: W/System.err(1165): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-24 18:03:23.484: W/System.err(1165):     at app.findme.map.MainActivity$GoogleMapFragment.initilizeMap(MainActivity.java:261)
04-24 18:03:23.484: W/System.err(1165):     at app.findme.map.MainActivity$GoogleMapFragment.onCreateView(MainActivity.java:244)
04-24 18:03:23.494: W/System.err(1165):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:828)
04-24 18:03:23.494: W/System.err(1165):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1032)
04-24 18:03:23.494: W/System.err(1165):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:622)
04-24 18:03:23.494: W/System.err(1165):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1382)
04-24 18:03:23.494: W/System.err(1165):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:426)
04-24 18:03:23.504: W/System.err(1165):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
04-24 18:03:23.504: W/System.err(1165):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-24 18:03:23.504: W/System.err(1165):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-24 18:03:23.504: W/System.err(1165):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
04-24 18:03:23.514: W/System.err(1165):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-24 18:03:23.514: W/System.err(1165):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-24 18:03:23.514: W/System.err(1165):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-24 18:03:23.524: W/System.err(1165):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-24 18:03:23.524: W/System.err(1165):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-24 18:03:27.805: D/dalvikvm(1165): GC_CONCURRENT freed 186K, 3% free 9287K/9543K, paused 8ms+6ms
04-24 18:03:29.425: D/AndroidRuntime(1165): Shutting down VM
04-24 18:03:29.425: W/dalvikvm(1165): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
04-24 18:03:29.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1165): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-24 18:03:29.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1165): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
04-24 18:03:29.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1165):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
04-24 18:03:29.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1165):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
04-24 18:03:29.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1165):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
04-24 18:03:29.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1165):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
04-24 18:03:29.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1165):     at app.findme.map.MainActivity$GoogleMapFragment.onCreateView(MainActivity.java:240)
04-24 18:03:29.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1165):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:828)
04-24 18:03:29.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1165):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1032)
04-24 18:03:29.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1165):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:622)
04-24 18:03:29.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1165):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1382)
04-24 18:03:29.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1165):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:426)
04-24 18:03:29.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1165):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
04-24 18:03:29.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1165):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-24 18:03:29.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1165):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-24 18:03:29.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1165):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
04-24 18:03:29.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1165):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-24 18:03:29.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1165):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-24 18:03:29.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1165):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-24 18:03:29.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1165):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-24 18:03:29.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1165):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-24 18:03:29.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1165): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #11: Duplicate id 0x7f050008, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
04-24 18:03:29.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1165):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4248)
04-24 18:03:29.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1165):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:673)
04-24 18:03:29.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1165):     ... 18 more
04-24 18:03:30.165: I/dalvikvm(1165): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-24 18:03:30.185: I/dalvikvm(1165): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-24 18:05:47.835: I/dalvikvm(1212): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-24 18:05:47.916: I/dalvikvm(1212): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-24 18:05:48.085: D/libEGL(1212): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
04-24 18:05:48.105: D/libEGL(1212): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
04-24 18:05:48.105: D/(1212): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x1d2f90, tid 1212
04-24 18:05:48.155: D/libEGL(1212): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
04-24 18:05:48.155: D/libEGL(1212): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
04-24 18:05:48.225: W/EGL_emulation(1212): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-24 18:05:48.235: D/OpenGLRenderer(1212): Enabling debug mode 0
04-24 18:05:48.335: I/dalvikvm(1212): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-24 18:05:48.356: I/dalvikvm(1212): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

MainActivity :

```
package app.track.map;

import java.util.Locale;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    private String[] mPlanetTitles;

    // Google Map
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    private static String SelectedMenuPosition;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.drawer_array);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
        // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
        // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                  /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
                ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            selectItem(0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.map, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_websearch).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
         // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
         // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action buttons
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_websearch:
            // create intent to perform web search for this planet
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
            intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, getActionBar().getTitle());
            // catch event that there's no activity to handle intent
            if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.app_not_available, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /* The click listner for ListView in the navigation drawer */
    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        SelectedMenuPosition = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.drawer_array)[position];
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        if ( position == 2){
            Fragment fragment = new GoogleMapFragment();

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        }
        else if( position == 3){
            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        }
        else
            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(SelectedMenuPosition.equals("Navigate")){
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) {
                googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
                return true;
            } 
            else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) {
                googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
public static class GoogleMapFragment extends Fragment {
        // Google Map
        private GoogleMap googleMap;

        public GoogleMapFragment() {
            // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

            try {
                // Loading map
                initilizeMap();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            getActivity().setTitle(SelectedMenuPosition);

            return rootView;
        }

        /**
         * function to load map. If map is not created it will create it for you
         * */
        private void initilizeMap() {
            if (googleMap == null) {
                googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
                googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
                googleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);
                googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
                googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

                LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.867, 151.206);

                googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 13));

                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .title("Sydney")
                        .snippet("The most populous city in Australia.")
                        .position(sydney));

                // check if map is created successfully or not
                if (googleMap == null) {
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Googlemap view :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in advance,

Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should override this method: (it destroys the google_map_fragment correctly after you clicked in another fragment ..)

```
  public void onDestroyView() 
     {
        super.onDestroyView(); 
        Fragment fragment = (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));  
        FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.remove(fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }
```

you have to override this method aswell if you want to initialize the map fragment everytime :)

```
@Override
public void onPause(){
super.onPause();
if(googleMap != null) {   
    googleMap = null;
  {
}
```

Comment: Where should I insert it exactly please ?

Comment: in your GoogleMapFragment class and add an @Override over the method-signature

Comment: It does work if only I change the fragment, but if I click twice on the same GoogleMap fragment, it craches :/

Comment: what do you mean by clicking twice in the fragment? i thought the problem is while switching between two fragments :o

Comment: no no, it works, I did counter the issue when I click on the slidermenu twice (which showing my googlemap frangment), with some if condition, and it works.
You rock thank you very much.

Comment: Do you think it's possible to keep the same googlemap status even if I switch fragment ??
Ex ; if I go to Sydney for example, and I switch fragment to another, and I wanna go back to my Googlemap and continue on Sydney, is that possible ?

Comment: No problem at all :) - private void initilizeMap() { should initialize everytime you open the google Map Fragment, if you handle it right. You could try to null your googleMaps Object in the end of onDestroyView :P

Comment: I don't want to initialize the map everytime, the contrary, I want to keep the same map status, means the same map long as the application is running. you see please ?

Comment: For example if I put some markers on the map, then I change the fragment to another stuff, and wanna go back to my map fragment, there is a way to keep the same map with later made details please ?